# Understanding BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

Could you help me understand BoxLayout. I want to organize something like that from javadoc for BoxLayout

please, have a look at the picture

[image]

Well, two rectangle panels were pictured Ok. But adding the first square brings about something unexpected by me. The first panel becomes longer by the side of the square. Adding another square ruins the picture even more. Well, adding the third square gives [this picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9-evERgNlKUbG5NR0syUFFPdUU/edit?usp=sharing). The frame is stretched manually to the full screen whereas initially the picture was supposed to ocupy only 600 x 600. If I don't stretch the window, the first panel occupies the whole space from top to bottom ane exhibits one and a half squares.

Could you help me understand what should I do to get the desired result?

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    public View(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        // LayoutManager for the whole frame.
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


        JPanel firstPanel = getPanel(200, 400);

        JPanel squareOne = getPanel(100, 100);
        JPanel squareTwo = getPanel(100, 100);
        JPanel squareThree = getPanel(100, 100);

        //firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        firstPanel.add(squareOne);
        //firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        firstPanel.add(squareTwo);
        //firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        firstPanel.add(squareThree);
        //firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());


        JPanel secondPanel = getPanel(200, 400);


        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        this.add(firstPanel);
        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        this.add(secondPanel);
        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel(int width, int height) {
        Border border = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.RED, Color.BLACK);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(width, height)));
        panel.setBorder(border);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**ADDED LATER:**

I changed the code like below. The picture has not changed.

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    public View(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        // LayoutManager for the whole frame.
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


        MyPanel firstPanel = getPanel(200, 400);

        MyPanel squareOne = getPanel(100, 100);
        MyPanel squareTwo = getPanel(100, 100);
        MyPanel squareThree = getPanel(100, 100);

        //firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        firstPanel.add(squareOne);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        firstPanel.add(squareTwo);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        firstPanel.add(squareThree);
        firstPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());


        MyPanel secondPanel = getPanel(200, 400);


        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        this.add(firstPanel);
        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        this.add(secondPanel);
        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
//
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel{
        int width;
        int height;
        public MyPanel(int width, int height){
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    }
    private MyPanel getPanel(int width, int height) {
        Border border = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.RED, Color.BLACK);
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(width, height);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(width, height)));
        panel.setBorder(border);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel` if needed.

```
JPanel panel =  new JPanel() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
};
```

Read more [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: Well, I have tried. Could you have a look at the code that I added to the initial post. Nothing changed.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Could you help me understand how to draw a picture like that in the documentation? Maybe I do something completely wrong? Why should I override some methods when the documentation clearly states: this layout manager is for this case. Maybe I used those glues in vain? But I really can't understand anything.